# How do I standardize a font-family and font size in a summernote?

Tags: javascript, summernote

I want to standardize the font and its size, when I open the table the font that appears to me is montserrat and the default size is 14

I want to leave the size at 11 and the initial font arial, I have already read the documentation and tested some codes

```
$('textarea#summernote').summernote({
        placeholder: 'Conteúdo da Capa do Processo',
        tabsize: 2,
        height: 300,
        lang: "pt-BR",
        fontSizeUnits: ['pt', 'px', 'vw'],
        fontNames: ['Arial', 'Arial Black', 'Comic Sans MS', 'Courier New'],
        toolbar: [
            // [groupName, [list of button]]
            ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
            ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
            ['color', ['color']],
            ['table', ['table']],
            ['fontname', ['fontname']],

        ]
      });
```

Problem image [image]

```
 .note-editor .note-editable {
    font-family: 'Arial'; //// I tried to use it, it went wrong
    font-size: '11px';
    }
```

```
$('#summernote').summernote('fontName', 'Arial');
    $('#summernote').summernote('fontSizeUnit', '11px');
    $('.note-editable').css('font-family','Arial'); //// I tried to use it, it went wrong 
    $('.note-editable').css('font-size','11px');
```